# Why 'dev tun' vpn uses tap adapter?

Tags: windows-10, openvpn

OpenVPN version 2.5.0 on windows 10. After the installation, I got two new network adapters: `OpenVPN Wintun` and `OpenVPN TAP-Windows6`.

My .ovpn configuration file contains the line `dev tun` so I was assuming the connection would have used the `tun` interface, but no, it uses the `tap` one. I tried reinstalling OpenVPN installing only the `tun` interface, and the connection fails with this log:

```
...
open_tun
MANAGEMENT: Client disconnected
All tap-windows6 adapters on this system are currently in use
Exiting due to fatal error
```

That makes sense because there's no `tap` adapter installed, but why doesn't it use the `tun` one if the config says so? The log even tells `open_tun`.

I tried changing `dev tun` to `dev tap` out of curiosity and it fails with multiple errors, so my vpn is really of the `tun` type. Can anyone explain me why it works this way? What's the use of the `OpenVPN Wintun` adapter if the `tap` one is used anyway?

If for any reason this behavior is correct, is it actually operating at level 3 like `tun` should or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Support for Wintun (brought in from WireGuard) is a very recent addition to OpenVPN 2.5, so you need to explicitly opt in to using it:

```
windows-driver wintun
```

For a long time, there *wasn't* anything resembling a 'tun' interface on Windows that could be used by OpenVPN, so `dev tun` had no choice but to use the "TAP-Windows" driver and create an L2 Ethernet interface even for a L3 tunnel – it would just emulate all L2 things (like ARP responses on the client side, even serving fake DHCP to the local machine.

However, as clunky as it was for layer-3 links, the "TAP-Windows "driver has worked for a long time and so remains the default for now. (Wintun also has been written with stricter permission checks, so OpenVPN needs to run as a service with System privileges. It seems that OpenVPN uses the "Interactive service" mode for this.)

Another similar option is OpenVPN's own "Data Channel Offload" driver `ovpn-dco`, which will become available with OpenVPN 2.6.

Comment: To clarify, this new `windows-driver wintun` line is added to the config file, along with keeping the existing `dev tun` ine.

Comment: I needed to add `windows-driver tap-windows6` instead of `wintun` to make it work.